# Cluster instability with TCPPING protocol

Tags: java, jgroups

I have 8 different processes distributed across 6 different servers with the following TCP/TCPPING protocol configuration:

```
<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">

  <TCP 
    bind_port="${jgroups.tcp.bind_port:16484}" 
    bind_addr="${jgroups.tcp.bind_addr:127.0.0.1}"
    recv_buf_size="20M"
    send_buf_size="20M" 
    max_bundle_size="64K" 
    sock_conn_timeout="300"
    
    use_fork_join_pool="true" 
    thread_pool.min_threads="10" 
    thread_pool.max_threads="100" 
    thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000" /> 
  <TCPPING 
    async_discovery="true"
    initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:127.0.0.1[16484]}"
    port_range="5" #/>
  <MERGE3 min_interval="10000" max_interval="30000" />
  <FD_SOCK get_cache_timeout="10000"
        cache_max_elements="300"
        cache_max_age="60000"
        suspect_msg_interval="10000"
        num_tries="10"
        sock_conn_timeout="10000"/>
  <FD timeout="10000" max_tries="10" />
  <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="10000" num_msgs="5"/>
  <BARRIER />
  <pbcast.NAKACK2
        max_rebroadcast_timeout="5000"
        use_mcast_xmit="false"
        discard_delivered_msgs="true" />
  <UNICAST3 />
  <pbcast.STABLE
        stability_delay="1000"
        desired_avg_gossip="50000"
        max_bytes="4M" />
  <AUTH
        auth_class="com.qfs.distribution.security.impl.CustomAuthToken"
        auth_value="distribution_password"
        token_hash="SHA" />
  <pbcast.GMS
        print_local_addr="true"
        join_timeout="10000"
        leave_timeout="10000"
        merge_timeout="10000"
        num_prev_mbrs="200"
        view_ack_collection_timeout="10000"/>
</config>
```

The cluster keeps splitting in subgroups, then merges again and again which results in high memory usages. I can also see in the logs a lot of "suspect" warning resulting from the periodic heartbeats sent by all other cluster members. Am I missing something ?

**EDIT**

After enabling gc logs, nothing suspect appeared to me. On the other hand, I've noticed this jgroups logs appearing a lot:

```
WARN: lonlx21440_FrtbQueryCube_QUERY_29302: I was suspected by woklxp00330_Sba-master_DATA_36219; ignoring the SUSPECT message and sending back a HEARTBEAT_ACK

DEBUG: lonlx21440_FrtbQueryCube_QUERY_29302: closing expired connection for redlxp00599_Sba-master_DATA_18899 (121206 ms old) in send_table

DEBUG: I (redlxp00599_Sba-master_DATA_18899) will be the merge leader

DEBUG: redlxp00599_Sba-master_DATA_18899: heartbeat missing from lonlx21503_Sba-master_DATA_2175 (number=1)

DEBUG: redlxp00599_Sba-master_DATA_18899: suspecting [lonlx21440_FrtbQueryCube_QUERY_29302]

DEBUG: lonlx21440_FrtbQueryCube_QUERY_29302: removed woklxp00330_Sba-master_DATA_36219 from xmit_table (not member anymore)enter code here
```

and this one

```
2020-08-31 16:35:34.715 [ForkJoinPool-3-worker-11] org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS:116
WARN: lonlx21440_FrtbQueryCube_QUERY_29302: failed to collect all ACKs (expected=6) for view [redlxp00599_Sba-master_DATA_18899|104] after 2000ms, missing 6 ACKs from (6) lonlx21503_Sba-master_DATA_2175, lonlx11179_DRC-master_DATA_15999, lonlx11184_Rrao-master_DATA_31760, lonlx11179_Rrao-master_DATA_25194, woklxp00330_Sba-master_DATA_36219, lonlx11184_DRC-master_DATA_49264
```

I still can;'t figure out where the instability comes from.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any instability is not due to `TCPPING` protocol - this belongs to the Discovery protocol family and its purpose is to **find new** members, not kick them out of the cluster.

You use both `FD_SOCK` and `FD` to find if members left, and then `VERIFY_SUSPECT` to confirm that the node is not reachable. The setting seems pretty normal.

First thing to check is your GC logs. If you experience STW pauses longer than, say, 15 seconds, chances are that the cluster disconnect because of unresponsiviness due to GC.

If your GC logs are fine, increase logging level for `FD`, `FD_SOCK` and `VERIFY_SUSPECT` to `TRACE` and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for those hints. Unfortunately, gc activity is normal. I updated the original post with some Jgroups logging ...